# Poor reconstructions from using sigmoid in last layer of variational autoencoder

Tags: neural-networks, python, autoencoders, variational-bayes

I have trained a variational autoencoder (VAE) using Pytorch Lightning to reproduce images.

Without `sigmoid`, reproductions are good. However, some output image values are negative so need to be clipped.

With `sigmoid` the reproductions are poor.

**Why is the sigmoid causing poor results?**

Using sigmoid to squash output into [0-1] seems a common approach but I just can't seem to get it working.

#### Input

Inputs to the pipeline are RGB image tensors with values in the range [0-1].

#### Output

Outputs from the decoder are RGB image tensors (visualised below) with values in the range [-1 to 1] without sigmoid and [0 to 1] with sigmoid.

```
self.kl_coefficient = 100
self.latent_dim = 8
self.input_image_height = 64
self.input_image_channels = 3
self.leaky_relu_negative_slope = 0.01

# Encoder / Decoder architecture
self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=self.input_image_channels, out_channels=8, kernel_size=4, stride=2),
    nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=self.leaky_relu_negative_slope),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=4, stride=2),
    nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=self.leaky_relu_negative_slope),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=4, stride=2),
    nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=self.leaky_relu_negative_slope),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4, stride=2),
    nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=self.leaky_relu_negative_slope),
    Flatten()
)
self.decoder = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(in_features=self.latent_dim, out_features=64),
    nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=self.leaky_relu_negative_slope),
    Unflatten(image_height=self.input_image_height),
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5, stride=2),
    nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=self.leaky_relu_negative_slope),
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=5, stride=2),
    nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=self.leaky_relu_negative_slope),
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=32, kernel_size=6, stride=2),
    nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=self.leaky_relu_negative_slope),
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=16, kernel_size=6, stride=2),
    nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=self.leaky_relu_negative_slope),
    nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=3, kernel_size=1, stride=1),
    nn.Sigmoid()  # Reproductions poor with sigmoid...but without the sigmoid, some of the pixel outputs go negative
)

# Fully connected layers
self.fc_pose_mu = nn.Linear(256, self.latent_dim)
self.fc_pose_log_var = nn.Linear(256, self.latent_dim)

def step(self, batch, batch_idx):

    reconstructed_images, q, p = self._run_step(batch)

    # 1. Reconstruction Loss (Mean Squared Error)
    reconstruction_loss = F.mse_loss(batch, reconstructed_images, reduction="sum")

    # 2. Training Stability Loss - latent distribution VS standard Gaussian (KL divergence)
    q_vs_standard_gaussian = torch.distributions.kl_divergence(q, p)
    training_stability_loss = q_vs_standard_gaussian.mean()
    training_stability_loss *= self.kl_coefficient

    # TOTAL loss
    return reconstruction_loss + training_stability_loss
```

#### Results

Top row are inputs, bottom left is **without** `sigmoid` and bottom right is **with** `sigmoid` (most pixels #000 or very close).

[image: Reconstructions from VAE]

Reconstruction loss when including the `sigmoid`, appears to converge to minimum:

[image]

### UPDATE #1

Batch norm (between the last `Conv2D` layer and the `sigmoid` layer) has helped the reconstructions.

```
nn.BatchNorm2d(3)
```

Although two further issues:

1. There are some consistent artefacts (see image) in the reconstructions
2. Background should be #000 black, but instead remains grey even after the object appears to be reconstructed well. Without batchnorm + sigmoid the background mostly goes to #000.

[image]

Comment: My hypothesis is that you'll need to tune the learning rate and maybe increase the number of training iterations.

Comment: Thanks @Sycorax, I'll post the reconstruction loss graphs but they both appear to converge on a minimum. Do you suspect the learning rate needs to be larger for the `sigmoid` version? Would that help it to jump out of a local minimum?

Comment: My hypothesis is that the network initializes in an area with really small gradients, due to the sigmoid function having 2 horizontal asymptotes. Increasing the learning rate might help.

Comment: Alternatively, you could put batch norm between the convolution layer and the sigmoid unit. This would change the model, but would help get the sigmoid activations to stay in the linear area and make it easier to train the network

Comment: @Sycorax larger learning rate hasn't helped, reconstructions go to black and reconstruction loss reaches local minimum quickly and remains there. Batchnorm after last convolutional layer has helped! Although two issues further issues...see update #1

Comment: How very odd! Whelp, I’m officially stumped.

Comment: No problem, thanks @Sycorax - I've posted a [follow up question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72816411/variational-autoencoder-reconstructions-artefacts-appear-that-persist-during-t)

Comment: What happens if you use something like binomial cross-entropy for the loss instead of MSE? Because binomial cross-entropy penalizes exponentially as you get farther from correct predictions, this might correct the weird artifacts, because they're *very* incorrect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137432/discussion-between-aktabit-and-sycorax).